# expect in bash script with special characters 2 parts

Tags: bash, expect

So I am trying to get expect within bash to work correctly.

Here is the script contents...

```
[root@mysql1 ~]# cat mysql_repl.sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Master server ip: " masterip
read -p "What is the regular user to log into the master server: " masteruser
read -p "What is the password for the regular user for the master server: " masterpass
read -p "What is the root password for the master server: " masterrootpass

read -p "Slave server ip: " slaveip
read -p "What is the regular user to log into the slave server: " slaveuser
read -p "What is the password for the regular user for the slave server: " slavepass
read -p "What is the root password for the slave server: " slaverootpass



expect -c "set slaveip $slaveip;\
set slaveuser $slaveuser;\
set slavepass $slavepass;\
set timeout -1;\
spawn /usr/bin/ssh $slaveip -l $slaveuser 'ls -lart';\
match_max 100000;
expect *password:;\
send -- $slavepass\r;\
interact;"
```

Here is the output of the script...

```
[root@mysql1 ~]# ./mysql_repl.sh
Master server ip:
What is the regular user to log into the master server:
What is the password for the regular user for the master server:
What is the root password for the master server:
Slave server ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
What is the regular user to log into the slave server: rack
What is the password for the regular user for the slave server: test
What is the root password for the slave server: DVJrPey99grJ
spawn /usr/bin/ssh 198.61.221.179 -l rack 'ls -lart'
rack@198.61.221.179's password:
bash: ls -lart: command not found
```

The command is not executing correctly. I also tried /bin/ls and it still can not find it.

Second Part... same script...

I have a variable in bash,  specifically, a password.  In this case the password is "as$5!@?"
What I want to do is go through each character, test if it is a special character and escape out of it.  So for instance...

```
pass=as$5!@?
```

What I have so far is close but not working for special characters, it will work for non-special...

```
echo -n $pass | while read -n 1 c; do [[ "$c" = [!@#$%^&*().] ]] && echo -n "\\"; echo -n $c; done
```

Anyone have thoughts on how I can add a \ before each special character?

Hope that clears up the question.

Comment: [This is not the problem you want to solve.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: So what I want to do is use 'expect -c' within a bash script because I am pretty decent at bash but know nothing about expect.  I am reading a password from a user and then assign that password to a variable.  I am taking that password and entering it into """expect -c "set timeout -1;\
spawn ssh ${slaveip} -l ${slaveuser} 'ls -lart';\
match_max 100000;
expect *password:*;\
send -- ${slavepass}\r;\
interact;"

Comment: Rather than just providing a list, can you define what makes a "special" character so special?

Comment: As for being "decent" in bash ... this is "covered with a towel" decent, right?  Not the sort of thing you'd show in public, but fine for an emergency ring of the door bell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last line block, try manually adding a \ before each special character that needs to be escaped. That shouldn't be much work.

Also, use == for the equality check, i.e.:

```
echo -n $pass | while read -n 1 c; do [[ "$c" == [!@#$%^&*().] ]] && echo -n "\\"; echo -n $c; done
```

Comment: This worked.... two things tho, I needed to put the pass in single quotes to not have it interpereted and needed to escape all the specials.  Thanks!